# Llamar resultado de un funcion desde otra función. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Se busca resolver el área de un circulo. Es facil Pi*Radio**2

Se piden los datos al usuario y da el resultado. Bien.

Pero ese mismo resultado (el area de ese circulo) debe servir para obtener el volumen de un cilindro (Volumen = 2*π*r*altura). Tambien pidiendo datos al usuario.

Todo ha de hacerse con funciones que llaman a funciones.
Estudié el tema de llamadas locales, invocaciones globales de funciones, pero no doy con la clave para mi programa.

Yo hago esto

```
def circulo():
    radio = float(input("Intro el radio del circulo en cms: "))
    area = 3.1415*(radio**2)
    print("El area del circulo es, ", round(area,2), "cms cuadrados")
    return (area)
circulo ()


def cilindro():     #Volumen = 2*π*r*altura
    altura = float(input("Intro la altura del cilindro en cms: "))
    volumen = area*altura
    print("El volumen del cilindro es, ", volumen, " cms cúbicos")
    return
cilindro()
```

Me dice que "area" en la funcion cilindro no está definida, claro que no, pero no se como llamarla o qué hacer.

En cambio...Si lo hago todo sin tener que introducir los datos del usuario si me funciona, por ejemplo hago esto y si que va:

```
def circulo_area(radio):
    pi = 3.1415
    return pi*radio**2

def cilindro(radio, altura):
    return circulo_area(radio)*high

print(cilindro(3,5))
```

Si me pudieses echar una mano con el primer código os lo agradecería. De tanto buscar (incluso en Stackoverflow hay dudas similares pero las pruebo en mi codigo y nada), asi que ya no se que hago mal. :-)
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uno de tus problemas es que las variables que asignas dentro de una función son **locales** a esa función; dejan de existir al momento de retornar. La variable `area` dentro de la función `circulo` sólo existe dentro de esa función.

Cuando mencionas `area` dentro de `cilindro`, aun cuando tiene el mismo nombre, es una variable distinta, que no ha sido inicializada, lo que es un error.

Veamos la forma correcta de programar. Primero que nada, debes separar E/S de los cálculos. Esto te permitirá reutilizar una misma función de cálculo en situaciones donde los datos los sacas de otra parte (de un archivo, de otro proceso, etc.) y te facilitara la depuración de tus funciones al evitarte tener que ingresar los datos una y otra vez cada vez que pruebes.

La forma correcta de definir una función es pasando los valores vía parámetro, no por variables globales. Los resultados deben entregarse vía `return`, sin variables globales.

Debes evitar/reducir el uso de variables globales, ya que se hace difícil entender el programa (la misma variable puede ser modificada en múltiples partes) y es fuente de interminables errores.

En el caso de la función `circulo`, el parámetro es el radio y lo que retorna es el área:

```
def circulo(radio):
    area = 3.1415*(radio**2)
    return area
```

Ahora podemos reutilizar esta función en el cálculo del volumen de un cilindro.

Para el volumen necesitamos dos parámetros (radio y altura) y retornamos el volumen:

```
def cilindro(radio, altura):     #Volumen = 2*π*r*altura
    area = circulo(radio)
    volumen = area * altura
    return volumen
```

Aquí tomamos el radio y usamos la función `circulo` para calcular el área, la que multiplicamos por la altura para obtener el volumen.

Ahora queda la interacción con el usuario:

```
radio = float(input("Intro el radio del circulo en cms: "))
area = circulo (radio)
print("El area del circulo es, ", round(area, 2), "cms cuadrados")

altura = float(input("Intro la altura del cilindro en cms: "))
volumen = cilindro(radio, altura)
print("El volumen del cilindro es, ", volumen, " cms cúbicos")
```

**Demo**

Lo anterior produce:

```
Intro el radio del circulo en cms: 50
El area del circulo es,  7853.75 cms cuadrados
Intro la altura del cilindro en cms: 100
El volumen del cilindro es,  785375.0  cms cúbicos
```

Comment: Una lección maravillosa @CandidMoe. Muchas gracias. Ahora si que comprendo y veo mis errores.